# Does the 'i' in 'iPhone' stand for anything?

Tags: terminology

Does the i in 'iPhone' stand for anything?

For example, when the word 'email' is used, it's just a shorter way to say 'electronic mail'.  When someone says 'eSports', it means 'electronic Sports'. So I'm curious if the i in iPhone or iPad or iTouch stands for anything? Like the iMac.  Did Apple just whimsically pick a letter prefix for their products? Or is there a word that it stands for.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's naming philosophy, not English; you'd really have to ask someone at Apple about this.

Comment: @Hellion consider the fact that many company names and logos have been turned into commonplace English words.  For example: "Have you tried Googling it?"

Comment: Did you know the meaning behind ‘i’ in iPod, iPhone and iPad? http://www.phonearena.com/news/Did-you-know-the-meaning-behind-i-in-iPod-iPhone-and-iPad_id52353

Comment: iKnow it but iAm not telling. OT.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the English language.

Comment: As my 91 year old father explained to me, it stands for the *interweb*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The i in front of Apple products was first used for the iMac. When Steve Jobs introduced the first iMac in 1998 he explained:

> iMac comes from the marriage of the excitement of the internet with the simplicity of Macintosh.  Even though this is a full-blooded Macintosh, we are targeting this for the number one use that consumers tell us they want a computer for, which is to get on the internet―simply, and fast.  And that is what this product is targeted for.
>
> "i" also means some other things to us.  We are a personal computer company, and although this product is born to network, it also is a beautiful stand-alone product.  We are targeting it also for education.  They want to buy these.  And it is perfect for most of the things they do in instruction.  It is perfect for finding tremendous sources of information over the Internet.  And we hope as you see the product it will inspire us all to make even better products in the future.
>
> ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BHPtoTctDY))

The words that appeared on the slide show at the time were **internet,  individual,  instruct,  inform,  inspire**.

**Internet** is probably the key word, as is reflected in the first paragraph of my quote and the sources in Choster's answer. One of the primary design goals of the first iMac was to reduce the mysterious and intimidating reputation the internet had at the time.

When Apple released the iPod, iPhone, iPad, etc. they probably continued this trend in part for recognizability and brand building, and in part because the much of same concepts and ideas behind the "i" were still applicable. Although ironically much less so for the iPod than its successor, the iPhone.

Comment: You didn't tell us "what the *i* is for in *iPhone,* though."

Answer (score 1):

Unlike *e-mail* or *U-bahn*, *iPod* and *iPad* and the like remain proprietary trademarks of Apple, and part of a naming convention that dates to 1998 with the iMac. That name, in turn, is attributed to Ken Segall, at the time working with Apple's advertising agency, according to a *[2012 Kansas City Business Journal](http://www.bizjournals.com/kansascity/news/2012/06/04/man-behind-imac-name-simplicity.html) article*:

> “I am the guy who came up with the ‘i,’” he said. Then-CEO Steve Jobs wanted the iMac to be a faster way for consumers to get on the Internet. Initially, he preferred *MacMan* for the name of the computer, but after Segall presented iMac to him twice, the name started to sink in. At the time, computers were Apple’s only business.
>
> “One of the reasons we liked it was it was a good foundational name just in case we ever wanted another i-word,” Segall said.

The [followup article](http://www.bizjournals.com/kansascity/blog/2012/06/man-who-came-up-with-imac-name-tells.html?page=all) further notes

> But what did the “i” really stand for? … “I hate to make it sound less magical than it may seem,” Segall said. It’s really about the Internet.… He reminded the audience of days when not everyone had an email address and connecting to the Internet was a challenge for the everyday consumer.
> The intent of the iMac was to take away some of this mystery and make the Internet more accessible, he said.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'i' prefix was first introduced with *iMac*, and it meant internet. But later it just stayed there for other products.